# Problem with material while rendering

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, shaders

I created an object for use in the scene but the material seems to be problematic even though it's just normal diffuse BSDF. I created a railing for the scene but the right side bottom two rails seem to have a different material. Please help and let me know if this is not a problem and if it looks normal.

Render Preview:
[image]

Comment: yes, looks kind of weird....

Comment: @chris any suggestions?

Comment: does this object have a second material slot? also worth checking normals, I don't know how many times it's bitten me

Comment: @AllenSimpson No, only one

Comment: have you checked the normals direction of your pipes ?